# How to upload aws lambda layer deployment package to s3 bucket using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to upload AWS Lambda's layer deployment package to s3 bucket using aws cli(since it's more than 50 megs), here is my command:

`aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name “layer name” --description "Layer description” --content S3Bucket=“s3-name/location”,S3Key=“package.zip”,S3ObjectVersion=“1” --license-info "MIT" --compatible-runtimes "nodejs8.10" --zip-file "fileb:////tmp/package.zip"`

I am just not sure about the --content part where I am specifying (S3Bucket, S3Key and S3ObjectVersion). N.B it works perfectly without --content

`aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name “layer name” --description "Layer description” --content S3Bucket=“s3-name/location”,S3Key=“package.zip”,S3ObjectVersion=“1” --license-info "MIT" --compatible-runtimes "nodejs8.10" --zip-file "fileb:////tmp/package.zip"`

With the above code, I get the following error message:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the PublishLayerVersion operation: Please do not provide other FunctionCode parameters when providing a ZipFile.

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1704

Answer (score 3):

You can try and create a json file, let's say "myJson.json"
and put inside:

```
{
  "S3Bucket": "s3-name",
  "S3Key": "location/package.zip",
  "S3ObjectVersion": "1"
}
```

then call it like this:

```
aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name “layer name” --description "Layer description” --content file://myJson.json --license-info "MIT" --compatible-runtimes "nodejs8.10" --zip-file file://tmp/package.zip
```

Please be aware you should execute the command where you created "myJson.json" (so move over to its location with "cd" command

By the way this :

```
--zip-file "file:////tmp/package.zip"
```

can be replaced by

```
--zip-file file://tmp/package.zip
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Glad it helped ;)

Comment: So this worked:

{
    "S3Bucket": "nextjs-portfolio",
    "S3Key": "batch-one.zip"
}

::: command :::

aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name "batch-one-of-nodejs-dependencies-layer" --description "Batch one of nodejs dependencies" --content "file://s3.json" --license-info "MIT" --compatible-runtimes "nodejs8.10"

Comment: Nice nice, so I guess your problem is solved :) Do you think you could close the issue ?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using file approach? I want to give parameters in the CLI